# How to filter table with WHERE clause before INNER JOIN in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, regex

With a little help from Stack Overflow I have managed to almost get the desired results from my database.

Basically I need to show a list of files that have a material column and a colour column where the most occurring `material & colour combo` is at the top.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT
  fileid,
  firstname,
  lastname,
  filename,
  material,
  colour,
  status,
  room,
  timesent,
  timecomplete,
  c_sent,
  c_fail
FROM 
  pro_files
  INNER JOIN pro_users ON pro_files.userid=pro_users.userid
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT material, colour, count(*) AS occ 
    FROM pro_files
    GROUP BY material, colour
  ) AS mcCounts  USING (material, colour)
WHERE
  laser=1
  AND status=1
  AND yr rlike '.'
  AND room rlike '.'
  AND "day" rlike '.'
  AND timesent > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
ORDER BY
  mcCounts.occ DESC, 
  pro_files.timesent ASC;
```

What this does it count the occurrences of `material & colour` from the whole database, ignoring the WHERE clause.

The returned results however do respect the where clause but the ordering is wrong because of the incorrect count.

I have tried loads of different combinations and moving lines around etc but I'm just not knowledgeable enough in MYSQL to do this.

Here is a example result from the above:
[image]

I've displayed the counts in the column occ. As you can see the top row occurs once so should read `1` but instead reads `9` because there are 9 rows in the entire database that have the material `5CCA` and no colour. The next row occurs twice so should read `2` on both columns and so on.

Here is my full files table I'm working with:
[File Table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NYjn5R5gkguNny5hLQXzmp0tlEmYBJr8Vve1wc7XIVQ/edit?usp=sharing)

And my users table in case it helps at all (no passwords of course):
[User Table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o0SEDP45Z9VC5Qozgm8e3wzbAMlobNy50XoIxWO1VmA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by the wrong count. It would help if you post a sample of rows from the tables, the query output produced by those rows as it is now, and the _desired_ query output.  I notice `"day" rlike...` in the `WHERE` is likely not doing what was intended. If `day` was meant to be quoted as a column identifier, it must be done with backticks in MySQL as `\`day\``, not double quotes. The double quotes would treat it as the literal string `'day'`, which would _always_ match the regex `.` no matter the row's contents.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I have added an example result and more detail. The `"day"` works well as far as I can tell, if I change them to back-ticks it returns no results at all.

Comment: `DAY` isn't a reserved word in MySQL requiring quoting of any kind anyway.  When you do `"day" REGEXP '.'` it is literally searching for any character in the string value "day". If it works when that's present but otherwise not, something else is wrong in the WHERE. Please post instead of a screenshot, actual copy/paste-able rows from the original tables. This will help us setup our own test cases, which is very often necessary to help debug a query.

Comment: Thanks Ill remember that In future. I have added full tables to the question.

Comment: Sounds like a [_Groupwise Max_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) problem.